# Hot code deployment during development with embedded Apache Felix and Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, osgi, apache-felix

I am trying to embed Felix in an application of ours to handle plugins. Everything is working fine, however, development and debugging is very cumbersome.

Is there a solution where I can tell Felix to automatically reload a plugin bundle or its classes when I recompile a plugin in Eclipse?

- I cannot use any OSGi specific launchers because Felix is embedded in our application
- Felix' fileinstall supports directories, but expects a specific structure, which is incompatible with the layout of the Eclipse project.

Any help or pointers to a solution would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at Bndtools and the remote launcher. You only need to install a remote agent in your framework and then Bndtools can update any bundle that has changed in the workspace.

This is explained in [remote launching](http://bnd.bndtools.org/chapters/300-launching.html). In OSGi enRoute you find an [IoT tutorial](http://enroute.osgi.org/tutorial_iot/050-start.html) that uses this model as well as a [Karaf App Note](http://enroute.osgi.org/appnotes/bndtools-and-karaf.html).